# Removing firemonkey from Windows taskbar

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Is there a way, to remove my firemonkey application form Windows XP/vista/7 taskbar? There is no info when i google.

**The problem:**

How to hide the form that is located in a dll from the Windows taskbar.

Comment: You can set `Application.MainFormOnTaskBar` to `False`. But it has no effect on the resulting app!

Comment: Are you writing a true FMX app, or are you just showing a single FMX form as part of a larger VCL app?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: its a dll form, the answer is in first post. Anyways, thank you for trying :)

Comment: Please move the solution part to an answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: @Talibek It would surely be easier to avoid using FMX. What feature of FMX are you using?

Comment: window transparency + cleartype font on canvas (AA) (some sort of OSD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*NB: [Talibek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620055/talibek) answered his own question within the question, for clarity I have moved it here.*

You need to get your main form handle (`Form1.Handle`), because there is no Application.handle in firemonkey, then convert it with `FmxHandleToHWND` (`FMX.Platform.Win`) to normal window handle. From your host application, you need to retrive that handle (you can export a function with it) and do this:

```
  h := GetHandle();

  ShowWindow(h, SW_HIDE);
  SetWindowLong(h, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(h, GWL_EXSTYLE) or 
      WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
  ShowWindow(h, SW_SHOW);
```

Retrieving handle:

```
class function TForm1.returnHandle(): integer;
begin
  result := FmxHandleToHWND(Form1.Handle);
end;
```

Of course, the `Application.MainFormOnTaskBar` property needs to be set to `true` so the form can handle the application.

Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: `Application.MainFormOnTaskBar` appears to be declared as a public field and then never references, at least in the FMX source that I can see.