# How to hide firemonkey application button from Taskbar (XE4)?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe3, firemonkey-fm2, delphi-xe4

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701511/removing-firemonkey-from-windows-taskbar) it is possible to hide fmx taskbar icon by changing window style to **WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW**.
In XE2 and XE3 this code works:

```
uses FMX.Platform.Win, Winapi.Windows;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var h:THandle;
begin
  h := FmxHandleToHWND(Handle);
  ShowWindow(h, SW_HIDE);
  SetWindowLong(h, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(h, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
  ShowWindow(h, SW_SHOW);
end;
```

In XE4 this solution does not work (application button should become hidden but nothing happens). any body have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: this work fine for me on XE3 (without MainformOnTaskbar): uses FMX.Platform.Win ;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 h:THandle;
begin
  h := FmxHandleToHWND(Handle);
  ShowWindow(h, SW_HIDE);
  SetWindowLong(h, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(h, GWL_EXSTYLE) or
      WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
  ShowWindow(h, SW_SHOW);
end;

Comment: MainformOnTaskbar determines whether or not the main form is unowned. Probably has no meaning in FMX where the main form is probably always unowned. So using tool window style will be enough.

Comment: Suggested code does not work on XE4.

Comment: Is it your goal to prevent your app from appearing on the taskbar all together(Icon + Title) or is it just removing the Icon(Title visible)?

Comment: My goal is only icon, the title is not important.

Comment: That's what I figured, you should know that the question you linked isn't really relevant to this question since there the goal was to remove the application from the taskbar all together (Icon+Title)

Comment: Well, I want to remove Icon+Title, ok?

Comment: you should change your question then to reflect your choice.

Comment: It's really poor when you say "doesn't work". Describe exactly how the code fails. Compile time? Runtime? Do not make us guess.

Comment: Taskbar icon should become hidden after click on button but nothing happens. It is clear that above code has no syntax problems. I'm surprised your comment.

Comment: It's not clear and "doesn't work" is never enough. Be explicit.

Comment: I found the solution.

Comment: Can you share the solution you have found please? I have a similar issue with hiding the taskbar button and changing its caption.

Comment: @VGeorgiev: I shared the requested code. Please upvote the question to negate unfair downvote ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
HWND hWnd = NULL;
DWORD pid, current_pid = GetCurrentProcessId();
do 
{
    hWnd = FindWindowExA(NULL, hWnd, "TFMAppClass", NULL);
    if(hWnd)
    {
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pid);
        if(current_pid == pid)
            break;
    }
} while(hWnd);

::SetParent(FmxHandleToHWND(Handle), NULL);
::ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: Thanks. The "TFMAppClass" pointed me in the right direction. I looked for something like that with Spy++, but have obviously missed it.

Comment: There is one problem with this code though. The `ShowWindow(FindWindowA("TFMAppClass", NULL), SW_HIDE)` will hide the first window with this class it finds, which might not be the one for your app. What if you have two Firemonkey apps running, or two instances of one... It would be better to use something like `FindWindow('TFMAppClass', PChar(ChangeFileExt(ExtractFileName(ParamStr(0)), '')))` or even better combine it with `GetWindowThreadProcessId` and `FindWindowEx` to check if ti belongs to your process.

Comment: You should be using `EnumWindows()` instead of calling `FindWindow()` in a loop.

Answer (score 4):

Just tried this in XE7 and of course it didn't work.  However a little look into FMX.PlatformWin shows the application handle is now exposed through the ApplicationHWND function, so the code that works on XE7 (don't forget to include unit `FMX.Platform.Win` and `Winapi.Windows`) is...

```
procedure HideAppOnTaskbar (AMainForm : TForm);
var
  AppHandle : HWND;
begin
  AppHandle := ApplicationHWND; 
  ShowWindow(AppHandle, SW_HIDE);
  SetWindowLong(AppHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(AppHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE) and (not     WS_EX_APPWINDOW) or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
  //ShowWindow(AppHandle, SW_SHOW);
end;
```

The ShowWindow at the end is optional - it seems to make no difference.  You can remove the extended styles and restore the WS_EX_APPWINDOW style to show the toolbar icon again.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that in XE4 FM apps there is no more handle for the application object.
So we need to get the parent of the main form.
Below two small methods to hide/show your app on the taskbar.

```
procedure HideAppOnTaskbar (AMainForm : TForm);
var
  AppHandle : HWND;
begin
  AppHandle := GetParent(FmxHandleToHWND(AMainForm.Handle));
  ShowWindow(AppHandle, SW_HIDE);
  SetWindowLong(AppHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(AppHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
end;

procedure ShowAppOnTaskbar (AMainForm : TForm);
var
  AppHandle : HWND;
begin
  AppHandle := GetParent(FmxHandleToHWND(AMainForm.Handle));
  ShowWindow(AppHandle, SW_HIDE);
  SetWindowLong(AppHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(AppHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE) and (not WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW));
  ShowWindow(AppHandle, SW_SHOW);
end;
```

We could also have used "Application.MainForm" instead of passing the mainform, but this variable is not assigned during the "OnCreate" Event of the mainform.

So in your "OnCreate" Event off your mainform you can simply write:

```
procedure TMyMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HideAppOnTaskbar (self);
end;
```

Comment: I tested suggested code. It does not work (has no effect). I think this code works only on XE3; also note that the function FmxHandleToHWND does not exists on XE4 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure HideAppOnTaskbar;
var
  appHandle: HWND;
  pid, current_pid: DWORD;
  name: String;

begin
  //ShowWindow(FindWindowA('TFMAppClass', nil), SW_HIDE);

  name := ChangeFileExt(ExtractFileName(ParamStr(0)), '');

  appHandle := 0;
  pid := 0;
  current_pid := GetCurrentProcessId();
  repeat
  begin
    //appHandle := FindWindowExA(0, appHandle, 'TFMAppClass', nil);
    appHandle := FindWindowExA(0, appHandle, 'TFMAppClass', PAnsiChar(AnsiString(name)));
    if (appHandle>0) then
    begin
      GetWindowThreadProcessId(appHandle, pid);
      if (current_pid = pid) then break;
    end;
  end
  until (appHandle>0);

  //SetParent(FmxHandleToHWND(Handle), nil);
  ShowWindow(appHandle, SW_HIDE);

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for Delphi 10.3, it might work in other versions too.

I don't know if you noticed, but whenever your code reachs **FormCreate** procedure, your FMX application will already have created a taskbar button, at least on Delphi 10.3.3 Rio, which is something we might not like. So if you use the suggested methods your application will fastly show its icon in the taskbar just to hide it.

So if you have access to Delphi's VCL/FMX source code files, and you don't like to show your application taskbar icon not even for a millisecond, you just have to modify `FMX.Platform.Win.pas` file located at `c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\source\fmx\` directory, then copy it to your projects directory, so it will be picked instead of the original one, and modify the `CreateAppHandle` function as suggested below:

```pascal
function TPlatformWin.CreateAppHandle: HWND;
var
 ...
begin
  ...
  Result := CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE or WS_EX_APPWINDOW, FMAppClass.lpszClassName, PChar(FTitle),
                           WS_POPUP or WS_GROUP, 0, 0, 0, 0, GetDesktopWindow, 0, hInstance, nil);
  if FApplicationHWND = 0 then // modified/added line
    Winapi.Windows.ShowWindow(Result, SW_HIDE) // modified/added line
  else // modified/added line
    Winapi.Windows.ShowWindow(Result, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

That's it, you won't need the other methods, notice it also has `CreateWindowEx` passing the styles for your window, if you want to hide it from Alt-Tab list too, replace `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` with `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` instead.