# Hide Taskbar button in FMX on Windows

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I want to be able to remove my Win32 application's button from the Taskbar.  I also want to be able to add it back later.  How can this be done?  I found [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768986/), but it is written in Delphi, and I'm using C++ instead.

I tried [modifying this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929163/) by changing one line of Remy's code from:

```
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, Style | WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
```

to

```
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, Style | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
```

But this doesn't work, the button is still on the Taskbar.

UPDATE:  the code I'm using (that originated from Remy of course):

```
void __fastcall TForm1::CreateHandle()   // this is code from Remy i added to help me trap screen lock
{
 TForm::CreateHandle();

 HWND hWnd = Fmx::Platform::Win::FormToHWND(this);
 if (SetWindowSubclass(hWnd, &SubclassWndProc, 1, reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(this)))
 {
    MonitoringWTS = WTSRegisterSessionNotification(hWnd, NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION);
    if (!MonitoringWTS)
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, &SubclassWndProc, 1);
 }
 else {
    MonitoringWTS = false;
 }

 if (hWnd != NULL)   // this code added from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929163/how-to-show-a-secondary-form-on-taskbar-using-fmx-c
 {
 LONG Style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE); // <-- don't forget this step!
 SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, Style | WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
 }
}
```

Using C++Builder 10.2 Version 25.0.31059.3231.

Comment: I tried setting BorderStyle to those options but the icon still shows up on the taskbar (Windows 10).  I tried the corrected `SetWindowLong` but doesn't remove the icon from taskbar either.  I'll post my code as UPDATE 1 above.

Comment: Which version of C++Builder are you using? Please include that in your update. It makes a big difference, as different versions handle FMX windows differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to just add the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` style if you also leave behind the default `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` style in place.  Try using this instead:

```
LONG_PTR ExStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, (Style & ~WS_EX_APPWINDOW) | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
```

Though, the easier way to make a `TForm` behave like a tool window is to simply set its `BorderStyle` property to `bsToolWindow` or `bsSizeToolWin`.

However, note that in XE7+, you should use [`ApplicationHWND()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.Win.ApplicationHWND) to get the `HWND` that is actually on the Taskbar, as it *may be different* than the `TForm`'s window. This was even [pointed out in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26259003/65863) to the question you dismissed just because it was written in Delphi instead of C++.  The relevant function calls don't change, just the code syntax.

Try this:

```
#include <FMX.Platform.Win.hpp>
#include <Winapi.Windows.hpp>

void HideAppOnTaskbar()
{
    HWND hAppWnd = Fmx::Platform::Win::ApplicationHWND();
    ShowWindow(hAppWnd, SW_HIDE);
    LONG_PTR ExStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(hAppWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    SetWindowLongPtr(hAppWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, (ExStyle & ~WS_EX_APPWINDOW) | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
    //ShowWindow(hAppWnd, SW_SHOW);
}

void ShowAppOnTaskbar()
{
    HWND hAppWnd = Fmx::Platform::Win::ApplicationHWND();
    ShowWindow(hAppWnd, SW_HIDE);
    LONG_PTR ExStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(hAppWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    SetWindowLongPtr(hAppWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, (ExStyle & ~WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW) | WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
    ShowWindow(hAppWnd, SW_SHOW);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::CreateHandle()
{
    //...
    HideAppOnTaskbar(); // or ShowAppOnTaskbar(), as needed
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you.  I also tried changing BorderStyle to every option and all still result in icon still on taskbar.  I tried that with a new FMX app to and same result (always icon on taskbar regardless of BorderStyle setting). I didn't know what to do with the Delphi code because i'm a fish out of water.

Comment: That is fantastic!

Comment: Remy - i load some user preferences from an SQLite db in the FormShow event.  I'd like to store a variable to control "hide" or "show" of the taskbar button.  It looks like the CreateHandle fires before the FormShow.  I tried my SQLite code in the CreateHandle function but it is too early I think and I get firedac errors.  I guess because the form isn't constructed and the firedac components aren't ready.  I'm thinking i may have to save that one preference (to show or hide taskbar button) to a text file.

Comment: @relayman357 try overriding the Form's `Loaded()` method, which is called after the DFM is done being streamed in.

Comment: This is beyond me so i took easy path and create a text file whose presence tracks the preference to hide or show the form button on taskbar.  Then in CreateHandle i simply test for the existence of that file (if present i hide).

Comment: @relayman357 using the Registry instead would make more sense than using a file.

Comment: As usual you are correct.  I found [this nice example](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Registry_TRegistry.html) of doing just that.  Thank you.